# my pom.xml install and build fail

Tags: java, maven, selenium

This is my pom.xml file for a java project that works with selenium to create a set of tests.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestMach</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestMach</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MainTestMach</name>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>main.ExtractMain</mainClass>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>-classpath</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1100-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.47.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>     
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

when I build it I get the following errors:

```
LF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

and

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.3:java (default-cli) on project TestMach: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: why are you not trying to add the slf4j dependency?

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: @Paolof76 i did and it gave the same errors

Answer (score 0):

As for the error in SLF4J, you can actually check the URL it mention (http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder).

As for the error when you run the application, the error is this

```
org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Seems like the error is happened when Selenium is trying to load the firefox driver as the selenium firefox driver version 2.47.1 is build with java version 7.

Try to run the application with higher java version to use jdk version 7 or try install the older version of firefox driver.

Answer (score 0):

Build with Java 7 or higher and your second problem should be fixed.

According to your error, the class `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver` has the class version of `51.0`, which suggests it's built for the target version of `Java 7`. Since you're using `Java 6`, loading that class fails. So upgrading your Java will fix the `InvocationTargetException`.